# Vue form empty field

Tags: forms, vue.js, vuetify.js

I made a form with vuetify, 
Name in the form is not required but if the user leave it blank and save the form I want the group to be named Unnamed, maybe if another form is completed, unnamed1, unnamed2 etc...

How can I do it?

In the form I made, it fill the name with unnamed, if I erase , I can named it with the name I like , but if I delete again, it refill with unnamed.

I think there is a better way to do it.

Here is a part of the code I made.

```
<template>
   <v-text-field
      v-if="groupName === '' ? groupName = 'Unnamed group' : 'name'"
      v-model="groupName"
   ></v-text-field>
<template>

<script>
    export default {
        },
        data() {
            return {
                groupName: ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not to have much logic in your template. You can define some method that will handle input change and then you can manipulate how you want with that input:

```
 <v-text-field @change="changeHandler" v-model="groupName">
 </v-text-field>
```

and then in your methods:

```
methods: {
   changeHandler(){
   if(this.groupName) {
      // do something with this.groupName
     } else {
      //do something else with this.groupName
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: So, what can I put in the if statement for example ?

Comment: You can manipulate this.groupName as you desire. If its not set you can set it on any value you need. Or lets say if you want to achieve to get "unnamed1" "unnamed2" you can define variable counter how many time user saved form. Make method that will save your input, and when save button is clicked you can increment  counter to add it as a suffix to your unnamed string to get unnamed unnamed2 etc. If you do not understand what I am  talking about as so I write peace of code for you.

Comment: I understand a little but if you help with some code that's will be cool

Comment: Hey Seb, here is a small example for you and I tried to explain with comments what is happening:
https://jsfiddle.net/0mpn5oex/1/